# Vue v-if destroys scrollbar plugin

Tags: vue.js

I try to use custom scrollbar using vuebar on dynamic Vue elements. Since v-if destroys and recreates elements, vuebar is not activated after that. On example provided you can see scrollbar works till you change tabs. I know you can use v-show and it starts working, but that solution is impossible to implement in nested components with complicated relations.

```
<div class="vuebar-element" v-bar v-if="tab==0">
  <div> 
    tab 0 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="vuebar-element" v-bar v-if="tab==1">
  <div> 
    tab 1 
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ebwdnqfs/2/

Comment: Have you considered using components and lifecycle hooks to conditionally add and remove the scrollbar plugin? https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: [Example 7](http://github.serafin.io/vuebar/#examples) of their documentation works with `v-if` and `v-bar` on the same element and it works perfectly fine. Try to find the difference between your example and theirs. You'll find the code [here](https://github.com/DominikSerafin/vuebar/blob/master/index.html). (line 1456)

Answer (score 0):

After reading comment from @ssc-hrep3 I discovered that putting whole thing into 
< transition > tag magically solves the problem.

```
<transition>
<div class="vuebar-element" v-bar v-if="tab==0">
  <div> 
    tab 0 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="vuebar-element" v-bar v-if="tab==1">
  <div> 
    tab 1 
  </div>
</div>
</transition>
```

Comment: Sounds like a fix, not a solution. They have an example here: http://github.serafin.io/vuebar/#examples

Comment: @Kordonme so is on their site. Example 7 with transition :/